# not able to export with powershell script

Tags: powershell, export

I am new to powershell. The following is my requirement:

Read a csv log file and based on the email field, I have to query and export the result to a csv file.

Below is a sample log file:

> emailid,date,time,client_ip,client_hostname,server_ip,server_hostname,source,event_id
>       manu@ionidea.com,05-24-2012,11:12:00,23.3.45.678,tytytyty,12.21.3.45,yuyuyuyuyu,hrertythghhdgfh,00928
>       ram@ionidea.com,06-05-2012,11:14:23,91.45.78.980,juqawessjj,16.51.5.93,pmbctr,ioyrhrtgdgdggdgjhjhj,00929
>       sheetal@ionidea.com,07-10-2012,11:12:00,10.0.87.369,yturbctyt,10.34.0.788,kokolioimdgf,brytifvnbty,00930

And I am using following script to do this:

```
function saveAndRun(){

    $var_newJob = $window.FindName("txtbox_JobName").Text+".txt";
    write-host $var_newJob
    $varArray_emailIds =  ($window.FindName("txtbox_Email").Text).split(',');
    $var_fromDate = "'"+ $window.FindName("txtbox_FromDate").Text+"'";
    $var_toDate =  "'"+$window.FindName("txtbox_ToDate").Text+"'";
    $list="";
    ForEach($var_emailid in $varArray_emailIds){
    $emailid = "'"+$var_emailid+"'";
    ForEach-Object{

    Import-Csv D:\Manu\Xtract\Log\MSLogFile.txt | Where-Object {$_.emailid -eq $emailid -and ($_.date -ge $var_fromDate -and $_.date -le $var_toDate ) }

    } | Export-Csv -Path D:\Manu\Xtract\extract\$var_newJob
    } 


}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? Wrong output, some error, other undesired behavior? What kind of output you would like to get from the sample log?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Export-Csv -Path "D:\Manu\Xtract\extract\$var_newJob.csv"
```